# Urn Probability Questions

Tags: logistic

An urn has 5 black balls and 4 white balls in it. We randomly sample a ball, and return it to the urn (sampling with replacement), until we get 2 balls with the same color. What is the probability that the first ball was white, if we know that the last one was white ? I tried building a tree, and realized that the experiment can have 2 or 3 stages, not more. Then I tried to fit conditional probability, but I got a fairly long fraction, which made no sense to me. Could you please help me to solve this problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Homework assignments require the `self-study` tag, and you should show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ P(\mbox{True} \vert \mbox{Damaged}) = 0.6$$

$$ P(\mbox{Damaged}) = 0.1$$

$$ P(\mbox{Damaged} \vert \mbox{True}) = ???$$

What theorem could you use to solve this?

> @$$ P(\mbox{Damaged} \vert \mbox{True}) = \dfrac{P(\mbox{True} \vert \mbox{Damaged}) P(\mbox{Damaged)}}{P(\mbox{True})} $$

Comment: @Dave Try a search for Bayes rule.  The application of Bayes rule is easy from this perspective.  Give it a try on your own and let me know what the result is.  If once after you try you still can not solve it, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$L$ = Total labels = 1,200

$L_D$ = # Damaged Labels = $10\% \cdot L = 120$

$T_D$ = # Damaged True labels = $60\% \cdot L_D = 72$

So of the 1,000 "True" labels, 72 are damaged.

$72/1000 = 7.2\%$